# Как добавить текст в Label в pyside2(pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Как мне добавить текст, не установить(`ui.setText()`) а добавить. Что бы старый текст не стёрся

Comment: `ui.setText(text + new_text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourlabel.setText(yourlabel.text()+"new text")
```